# AppInstaller fails when pointing MainBundle to HTTPS URI but works when pointing to FILE:/// URI

Tags: msix, appinstaller

I'm having an annoying issue with my AppInstaller file giving an error when trying to install an MSIXBundle file from a HTTPS URI:

```
App installation failed with error message: error 0x8007000D: Opening the package from location {package_name}.dev.msixbundle failed. (0x8007000d)
```

[MSIXBundle Install Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQY7m.png)

The AppInstaller file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AppInstaller Uri="https://{domain}/{package_name}.dev.appinstaller" Version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2018">
  <MainBundle Name="{package_name}" Version="0.6.220.0" Publisher="CN={publisher}" Uri="https://{domain}/{package_name}.dev.msixbundle" />
  <UpdateSettings>
    <OnLaunch HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0" ShowPrompt="true" />
  </UpdateSettings>
</AppInstaller>
```

If I download the AppInstaller and MSIXBundle files locally and change the HTTPS protocol to be FILE:/// within the AppInstaller file, then it works fine. I can keep the AppInstaller Uri in the file to FILE:/// and set the MainBundle Uri to HTTPS and then it fails as well.

I've noticed that this only started happening on the latest 2 version of Windows 10 (i.e 2004 and 20H2). If I restart my PC, then the HTTPS protocol works fine and I can install the package by referencing the  hosted AppInstaller file. But when I update the AppInstaller to indicate a new version of the Package has been released, I get the above mentioned error again during the update process. I've I uninstall the package completely and try to install it again, I get the error as well.

I've been unable to find a reliable solution for this issue, so I was hoping some clever people out there might be able to help or at least point me in an alternative route if the AppInstaller is too buggy on the latest versions of Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Although the post is a bit older, I'd like to share my experience with a similar behavior.

I got the error code when hosting the installer files using a self signed certificate (SSL not code sign) for the server.
After installing the root certificate to 'Trusted Root Certificates' of the local computer (installing for current user did not fixed the error), the installer worked as expected.

I'm not sure if this was your problem, since the installation worked after restarting the computer. For me the appinstaller never worked as long as I had the certificate not installed.